# Finding Matching Columns - SQL or Excel Formula no Macros, Where Match Found

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula, inner-join

Apologize in advance if I don't explain myself properly and bad spelling etc. I am Dyslexic so find these things difficult.

I have a SQL table Clean_Room_Doors, this contains a SALES_ORDER and DOOR_REF. These two fields are my primary keys as I can not have the duplicates of the same SALES_ORDER + DOOR_REF. I have another SQL table Clean_Room_Doors_Frames with the same set up SALES_ORDER + DOOR_REF as primary key.

I now need either a SQL query or an Excel formula, can not be macro as its an emailed report. I want the query/formula to find me values from the two tables that are duplicates of SALES_ORDER + DOOR_REF between the two tables. i.e.

Clean_Rooms_Doors SALES_ORDER + DOOR_REF that match SALES_ORDER + DOOR_REF in Clean_Room_Doors_Frames

Hope this make sense and thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Hi Steve - what have you tried so far. what you are trying to achieve is possible in either Excel or via SQL - I imagine SQL would be preferred?

Comment: Hi maxhob17, Thanks for the reply. I am more comfortable with SQL however it can also be Excel as the tables are linked to a spreadsheet for the report. If I am honest I have  attempted much as not really sure where to start and everything I have tried so far hasn't generated much worth noting . I am fairly new to SQL and Excel so wanted to see what people suggested to get me started. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can `join`:

```
select crd.sales_order, crd.door_ref
from clean_room_doors cdr
inner join clean_room_doors_frame crdf
    on  crdf.sales_order = cdr.clean_room_doors and crdf.door_ref = cdr.door_ref
```

This brings tuples of `(sales_order, door_ref)` that are available in both tables.

You could also do this with `exists`:

```
select crd.*
from clean_room_doors cdr
where exists (
    select 1 
    from clean_room_doors_frame crdf
    where crdf.sales_order = cdr.clean_room_doors and crdf.door_ref = cdr.door_ref
)
```